# Как нормально выводить таблицу в терминал? Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

[image: .]Получается вот что, а хотелось бы как нибудь нормально посмотреть на нее.

Comment: Она нормально выведена, просто она шире, чем помещается в окно, вот и расползлась.

Comment: Откройте в чём-нибудь более графическом, например PgAdmin.

Comment: http://merlinmoncure.blogspot.com/2007/10/better-psql-with-less.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В консоли PSQL (судя по скрину) дайте команду \x
это режим когда поля списком выводятся.
Дав повторно \x - все вернется в исходный режим.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]